# Randomly sampling a population and keeping means: tidy up, generalize, document?

Tags: python, random

This is part from an [answer to a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706151/python-3-1-memory-error-during-sampling-of-a-large-list/4706317#4706317). The OP needed a way to perform calculations on samples from a population, but was hitting memory errors due to keeping samples in memory.

The function is based on part of [random.sample](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/random.py?view=markup#sample), but only the code branch using a set is present.

If we can tidy and comment this well enough, it might be worth publishing as a recipe at the [Python Cookbook](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/).

```
import random

def sampling_mean(population, k, times):
    # Part of this is lifted straight from random.py
    _int = int
    _random = random.random

    n = len(population)
    kf = float(k)
    result = []

    if not 0 <= k <= n:
        raise ValueError, "sample larger than population"

    for t in xrange(times):
        selected = set()
        sum_ = 0
        selected_add = selected.add

        for i in xrange(k):
            j = _int(_random() * n)
            while j in selected:
                j = _int(_random() * n)
            selected_add(j)
            sum_ += population[j]

        # Partial result we're interested in
        mean = sum_/kf
        result.append(mean)
    return result

sampling_mean(x, 1000000, 100)
```

Maybe it'd be interesting to generalize it so you can pass a function that calculates the value you're interested in from the sample?

Comment: But you keep the samples in memory too, so this isn't an improvement, over the solution you gave him, namely not keeping the samples around but calculating each mean directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a generator version of `random.sample()` seems to be a much better idea:

```
from __future__ import division
from random import random
from math import ceil as _ceil, log as _log

def xsample(population, k):
    """A generator version of random.sample"""
    n = len(population)
    if not 0 <= k <= n:
        raise ValueError, "sample larger than population"
    _int = int
    setsize = 21        # size of a small set minus size of an empty list
    if k > 5:
        setsize += 4 ** _ceil(_log(k * 3, 4)) # table size for big sets
    if n <= setsize or hasattr(population, "keys"):
        # An n-length list is smaller than a k-length set, or this is a
        # mapping type so the other algorithm wouldn't work.
        pool = list(population)
        for i in xrange(k):         # invariant:  non-selected at [0,n-i)
            j = _int(random() * (n-i))
            yield pool[j]
            pool[j] = pool[n-i-1]   # move non-selected item into vacancy
    else:
        try:
            selected = set()
            selected_add = selected.add
            for i in xrange(k):
                j = _int(random() * n)
                while j in selected:
                    j = _int(random() * n)
                selected_add(j)
                yield population[j]
        except (TypeError, KeyError):   # handle (at least) sets
            if isinstance(population, list):
                raise
            for x in sample(tuple(population), k):
                yield x
```

Taking a sampling mean then becomes trivial:

```
def sampling_mean(population, k, times):
    for t in xrange(times):
        yield sum(xsample(population, k))/k
```

That said, as a code review, not much can be said about your code as it is more or less taking directly from the Python source, which can be said to be authoritative. ;) It does have a lot of silly speed-ups that make the code harder to read.